# Eigenfunctions of the Laplacian under a change of coordinates

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, eigenfunctions

The review paper by Grebenkov and Nguyen 2013 analyzes the eigenvalue problem,
$$
-\nabla^2 u_n(x) = \lambda_n u_n(x)
$$
on a domain $x \in \Omega$. We can also assume Dirchlet boundary conditions, $u_n = 0$ on $\partial \Omega$. The paper suggests that the eigenfunctions and eigenvalues depend only on the domain $\Omega$ and the boundary conditions, rather than the coordinate system used to express the Laplacian. For example, if we consider the spherical shell $\Omega = \left( x \in \mathbb{R}^3 : a \leq ||x|| \leq b \right)$, then the solutions are well known, namely,

$$
u_{nkl} = \begin{pmatrix} j_n(\alpha_{nk} r / b), \\ y_n(\alpha_{nk} r / b) \end{pmatrix} Y_l^m(\theta,\phi)
$$

where $j_n,y_n$ are spherical Bessel functions, and the coefficients $\alpha_{nk}$ are determined from the boundary conditions. This solution is obtained by expressing the Laplacian operator in spherical coordinates, $(r,\theta,\phi)$ and doing separation of variables.

Suppose I want to use a different coordinate system, $(r,\alpha,\beta)$ where the angles $(\alpha,\beta)$ also chart the sphere but are nonlinear functions of $(\theta,\phi)$:
\begin{eqnarray}
\alpha &= \textrm{acos}(\cos{\theta} \sin{\phi}), \\
\beta &= \phi
\end{eqnarray}

How would I define an appropriate domain $\Omega$ for this coordinate system? In the case of spherical coordinates, the domain $\Omega$ is defined as surfaces of constant $r$, leading to a spherical shell domain. Would this also be the natural domain to use for my new coordinate system, since the new coordinates also have a radial parameter? Or would the domain be somehow a distorted shell, due to the nonlinear transformation of the angular variables?

In other words, how does one define a natural domain $\Omega$ for a given coordinate system?

Grebenkov and Nguyen, Geometrical structure of Laplacian eigenfunctions, SIAM Review, 55, 2013.

Comment: The eigenfunctions must be the same because the problem you are solving hasn't changed. This is a kind of tautology because this is how coordinate transformations are defined.

Comment: Thanks for your comment and I agree with what you said. I have modified my question to ask whether the domain $\Omega$ should be modified for the new coordinate system, or whether the natural domain for the new coordinates is also a spherical shell.

Comment: If you change coordinates from $x \in \Omega$ to $y$ via $x = F(y)$, then your $y$ coordinates are defined on $F^{-1}(\Omega)$ since $y = F^{-1}(x)$. So yes, when you change coordinates, the domain on which you work changes.